# Symfony using DiscriminatorColumn with formbuilder

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a user entity:

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @package Somepackage
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Somepackage\UserBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"usereins" = "UserEins", "userzwei" = "UserZwei", "admin" = "Admin"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
```

Now I want to create a form with formbuilder, where a new user can be created and the "discr" can be selected via dropdown. But if I try this:

```
$builder
        ->add('discr', 'choice', array( ... ), 'required' => true ));
```

then Symfony says:

> Neither the property "discr" nor one of the methods "getDiscr()", "isDiscr()", "hasDiscr()", "__get()" exist

How can I do this? Is it possible? I have been googling for over an hour and I cannot seem to find anything except other stackoverflow questions no one has been able to answer.

Comment: Check your User entity, if you created gettter and setter for "discr".

Comment: Won't work.  Doctrine 2 sets the discr column based on class type. It's value is simply not exposed to your application.  Even if you add getters/setters and fake a discr property it won't do you any good.  Doctrine 2 will ignore it.  If you want to pick the class of the user object based on a form option then you will need to add some logic after your $form->isValid to create the appropriate class and then transfer the posted form properties.

Comment: I don't really understand the schema you are doing and why you are doing the inheritance in the first place.  You're using single-table inheritance which means different tables could be created.  You could create an initial unmapped select list that gives you the options, then based on what is chosen you in the POST data can load individual forms for the other entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cerads answer is correct, thank you very much. I added another field to my table in which I store the type of user, so I didn't have to worry about the discr field.